# Drawing a Line in 3D using DirectX 11

Tags: shaders, directx

I had a lot of problems to draw a line in a 3D and had a weird results.. The 3D Lines are projects in 2D and that's so weird. They only work with that view matrix configuration:

```
XMVECTOR Eye = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 3.0f, -6.0f, 0.0f);
XMVECTOR At = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
XMVECTOR Up = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
XMMATRIX g_View = XMMatrixLookAtLH(Eye, At, Up);


basicEffect->SetView(g_View);
```

but when I use my camera view matrix they get projected in 2D.. however I have my terrain rendered correctly and other things..

Here is my Camera class:

```
void cCamera::Initialize()
{
Reset();
}


void cCamera::Reset()
{
// config for left hand camera system
m_Position = XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
m_Forward = XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
m_Up = XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
m_Right = XMFLOAT3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

UpdateViewMatrix();
}

const XMFLOAT3& cCamera::Position() const
{
return m_Position;
}

const XMFLOAT3& cCamera::Forward() const
{
return m_Forward;
}

const XMFLOAT3& cCamera::Up() const
{
return m_Up;
}

const XMFLOAT3& cCamera::Right() const
{
return m_Right;
}

float cCamera::AspectRatio() const
{
return m_AspectRatio;
}

float cCamera::FieldOfView() const
{
return m_FieldOfView;
}

float cCamera::NearPlaneDistance() const
{
return m_NearPlaneDistance;
}

float cCamera::FarPlaneDistance() const
{
return m_FarPlaneDistance;
}

XMMATRIX cCamera::ViewMatrix()
{
return XMLoadFloat4x4(&m_ViewMatrix);
}

XMMATRIX cCamera::ProjectionMatrix()
{
return XMLoadFloat4x4(&m_ProjectionMatrix);
}

XMMATRIX cCamera::ViewProjectionMatrix()
{
XMMATRIX viewMatrix = XMLoadFloat4x4(&m_ViewMatrix);
XMMATRIX projectionMatrix = XMLoadFloat4x4(&m_ProjectionMatrix);

return XMMatrixMultiply(viewMatrix, projectionMatrix);
}


void cCamera::SetPosition(const XMFLOAT3& position)
{
m_Position = position;
}

void cCamera::SetPerspective(float fov, float aspect, float nearPlane, float farPlane)
{
m_FieldOfView = fov;
m_AspectRatio = aspect;
m_NearPlaneDistance = nearPlane;
m_FarPlaneDistance = farPlane;

XMMATRIX projectionMatrix = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(m_FieldOfView, m_AspectRatio, m_NearPlaneDistance, m_FarPlaneDistance);
XMStoreFloat4x4(&m_ProjectionMatrix, projectionMatrix);
}
void cCamera::SetOrthographic(float viewWidth, float viewHeight, float zn, float zf)
{
XMMATRIX projectionMatrix = XMMatrixOrthographicLH(viewWidth, viewHeight, zn, zf);
XMStoreFloat4x4(&m_ProjectionMatrix, projectionMatrix);
}
void cCamera::LookAt(const XMVECTOR &target)
{
XMVECTOR p = XMLoadFloat3(&m_Position);
XMVECTOR look = target - p;
XMStoreFloat3(&m_Forward, look);
}

void cCamera::UpdateViewMatrix()
{
XMVECTOR eyePosition = XMLoadFloat3(&m_Position);
XMVECTOR direction = XMLoadFloat3(&m_Forward);
XMVECTOR upDirection = XMLoadFloat3(&m_Up);

XMMATRIX viewMatrix = XMMatrixLookToLH(eyePosition, direction, upDirection);
XMStoreFloat4x4(&m_ViewMatrix, viewMatrix);
}


void cCamera::Update(float dt)
{
if (GetAsyncKeyState('W') & 0x8000)
    Walk(45 * dt);

if (GetAsyncKeyState('S') & 0x8000)
    Walk(-45 * dt);

if (GetAsyncKeyState('A') & 0x8000)
    Strafe(-45 * dt);

if (GetAsyncKeyState('D') & 0x8000)
    Strafe(45 * dt);

if (GetAsyncKeyState('Z') & 0x8000)
    MoveUp(-45 * dt);

if (GetAsyncKeyState('X') & 0x8000)
    MoveUp(45 * dt);

UpdateViewMatrix();
}

void cCamera::MoveUp(float d)
{
// mPosition += d*Up
XMVECTOR s = XMVectorReplicate(d);
XMVECTOR u = XMLoadFloat3(&m_Up);
XMVECTOR p = XMLoadFloat3(&m_Position);
XMStoreFloat3(&m_Position, XMVectorMultiplyAdd(s, u, p));
}

void cCamera::Strafe(float d)
{
// mPosition += d*Right
XMVECTOR s = XMVectorReplicate(d);
XMVECTOR r = XMLoadFloat3(&m_Right);
XMVECTOR p = XMLoadFloat3(&m_Position);
XMStoreFloat3(&m_Position, XMVectorMultiplyAdd(s, r, p));
}

void cCamera::Walk(float d)
{
// mPosition += d*Forward
XMVECTOR s = XMVectorReplicate(d);
XMVECTOR l = XMLoadFloat3(&m_Forward);
XMVECTOR p = XMLoadFloat3(&m_Position);
XMStoreFloat3(&m_Position, XMVectorMultiplyAdd(s, l, p));
}

void cCamera::Pitch(float angle)
{
// Rotate up and forward vector about the right vector.

XMMATRIX R = XMMatrixRotationAxis(XMLoadFloat3(&m_Right), angle);

XMStoreFloat3(&m_Up, XMVector3TransformNormal(XMLoadFloat3(&m_Up), R));
XMStoreFloat3(&m_Forward, XMVector3TransformNormal(XMLoadFloat3(&m_Forward), R));
}

void cCamera::RotateY(float angle)
{
// Rotate the basis vectors about the world y-axis.

XMMATRIX R = XMMatrixRotationY(angle);

XMStoreFloat3(&m_Right, XMVector3TransformNormal(XMLoadFloat3(&m_Right), R));
XMStoreFloat3(&m_Up, XMVector3TransformNormal(XMLoadFloat3(&m_Up), R));
XMStoreFloat3(&m_Forward, XMVector3TransformNormal(XMLoadFloat3(&m_Forward), R));
}
```

That's the result of a drawing a line in 3D Cords

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "The 3D Lines are projects in 2D and that's so weird"? How is the rendered line you showed not correct?

Comment: i think he means that the line looks to be renderd in 2d. If you render a line in 3d it will look 2d, because there is nothing to define it, there is no width in it, you would have to render a thicker line to get any sort of 3d illusions with it. imagine looking straight trough the line, you would not see anything because it´s just one pixel wide.

Comment: I'm trying to render wireframe lines(grid) or any other lines of a wireframe box, the result is just lines with no depth at all.

Comment: @Tordin The problem is when I let the shader use the view matrix that I showed above, it work very correctly(I tested it by rendering a grid of lines), but when I use my own camera view matrix, the result is a line that is rendered in 2D

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DirectXTK-Simple-Win32-23db418a
The At and Up is copied from the above sample which uses a grid of lines and they are rendered correctly :S

Comment: @Tordin here is a complete project. Please run bullet physics demo https://www.mediafire.com/?7pm4c1bh9h7i3n6

Comment: It´s super hard to actually understand your question. could you illustrate the correct vs the wrong results somehow?

Comment: @Tordin I'm trying to draw a line in 3D the line looks like its rendered in 2D.. If I try to draw a grid, I only see a horizontal line. I should see a grid of lines. The two view matrix above changes the results from wrong to correct. I don't know why the view matrix affects the line rendering

Comment: NOTE ``XMMatrixLookAtLH`` takes a POSITION to look at, not a direction. That is why "at" (0,1,0) and "up" (0,1,0) works. "at" is the position 0,1,0. ``XMMatrixLookToLH`` takes a direction instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the difference between [XMMatrixLookToLH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.matrix.xmmatrixlooktolh.aspx) and [XMMatrixLookAtLH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.matrix.xmmatrixlookatlh.aspx).

The DirectX TK SimpleSample is using `XMMatrixLookAtLH` which is computing:

```
XMVECTOR Eye = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 3.0f, -6.0f, 0.0f);
XMVECTOR At = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
XMVECTOR Up = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
XMMATRIX g_View = XMMatrixLookAtLH(Eye, At, Up);
```

Here "At" is the *position* 0, 1, 0 and is used as the **focus position** (i.e. it computes the eye direction from Eye and At).

Your camera code is using `XMMatrixLookToLH`, which is failing to get the right result because you are passing (0,1,0) as the **EyeDirection** and **UpDirection** which naturally fails.

Comment: If I want to use XMMatrixLookToLH what should I change?

Comment: Set At to (0,0,1).